How to fix the null that keeps popping up on my code
I'm using codehs for my ap comsci, and I'm stuck on using contructor but keep getting the words null with the sentences I want.
public class Pinata
{
    private String candy;  
    private String color;    
    private String shape;
    
    public Pinata()
    {
        candy = "hard candy";
        color = "rainbow";
        shape = "donkey";
    }
    
    public Pinata(String candyType, String colorType, String shapePin)
    {
        candy = candyType;
        color = colorType;
        shape = shapePin;
    }
    
    public Pinata(String colorType, String shapePin)
    {
        color = colorType;
        shape = shapePin;
    }
    
    
    public Pinata(String candyType)
    {
        candy = candyType;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return color + " " + shape + " pinata filled with " + candy;
    }
}

I tried using this code and have the other file was set to this
public class PinataTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Make Pinatas!
        Pinata ella = new Pinata();
        Pinata pete = new Pinata("chocolate", "blue", "star");
        Pinata sweetie = new Pinata("sour straws");
        
        // Print the pinatas
        System.out.println(ella);
        System.out.println(pete);
        System.out.println(sweetie);
        
        
    }
}

but all I get is an error saying the image uploaded;
test error
Any idea on how to fix?

I guess that's likely due to the constructor not initializing all fields correctly in some instances, which is why you're seeing null in your output. The fields that are not explicitly set (like color or candy) remain uninitialized, resulting in null values, may be set default values in the constructor when fields are not explicitly initialized.?

Or maybe in your toString method leave out fields that are null?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have clearly stated what’s the problem with your code, that’s good when asking about code that doesn’t work as expected or desired. Please always also (and maybe first) tell us the desired behaviour so we can guide you to obtaining that. We’re not thought readers and can’t guess what you would have wanted instead of your null.

It looks like the issue you're facing comes from the fact that some of your constructors don't initialize all the fields, which means some of them are left as null. In Java, when you don't assign a value to an object (like a String), it defaults to null. That's why you're seeing null in your output.
For example, in the constructor Pinata(String candyType), you only set the candy variable, but color and shape are left uninitialized, so they default to null.
You can fix it by ensuring all constructors provide values for all fields, either through the constructor parameters or by giving default values.
Here’s one way to fix your Pinata class using constructor chaining. This means that instead of writing the same initialization logic in each constructor, the shorter constructors can call the main one, passing default values where needed:
class Pinata {
  private String candy;
  private String color;
  private String shape;

  // Constructor with all fields
  public Pinata(String candyType, String colorType, String shapePin) {
    candy = candyType;
    color = colorType;
    shape = shapePin;
  }

  // Default constructor (calls the main constructor)
  public Pinata() {
    this("hard candy", "rainbow", "donkey");
  }

  // Constructor with color and shape only (uses default candy)
  public Pinata(String colorType, String shapePin) {
    this("hard candy", colorType, shapePin);
  }

  // Constructor with candy only (uses default color and shape)
  public Pinata(String candyType) {
    this(candyType, "rainbow", "donkey");
  }

  public String toString() {
    return color + " " + shape + " pinata filled with " + candy;
  }
}

class PinataTester {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Make Pinatas!
    Pinata ella = new Pinata();
    Pinata pete = new Pinata("chocolate", "blue", "star");
    Pinata sweetie = new Pinata("sour straws");
    // Print the pinatas
    System.out.println(ella);
    System.out.println(pete);
    System.out.println(sweetie);
  }
}

Output:
rainbow donkey pinata filled with hard candy
blue star pinata filled with chocolate
rainbow donkey pinata filled with sour straws


In java every variable must have a value before it can be used. If you dont initialize variable it will get default value. You can read about it in java language specification. In some of your constructors you dont initialize variables, so they get their default values - null for reference type (String is a reference type).
All you need is to initialize ALL your variables in ALL your constructors. For example the second constructor can be written this way:
public Pinata(String colorType, String shapePin)
{
    color = colorType;
    shape = shapePin;
    candy = "hard candy";
}


Or maybe: this(colorType, shapePin, "hard candy")

In Java, if you're instantiating the object with a parametrised constructor and only initialising some of your variables in it, the other variables do not get initialised automatically from the default constructor.
In current versions of Java, an initialised String is represented as null instead of an "" as earlier.
In your example, you have initialised only candytype in the called constructor, due to which other variables are null.

You wrote (in your answer): In current versions of Java, an initialised String is represented as null instead of an "" as earlier. Are you saying that an uninitialized String class member variable is implicitly initialized to an empty string? If you are, then I don't remember any Java version where this was true and I have been using Java since version 1.1 was released. Which version are you referring to?

An uninitialized reference field (instance variable or static variable, for example of type String) was always null since Java 1.0. They would never dare to change this behaviour. Compatibility is important.
